# Rewriting e.preventDefault() for IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I'm having trouble with `e.preventDefault()` in IE8 as it is causing the following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method `preventDefault`
```

As seen in other threads and on Google, this can be avoided by using `e.returnValue` as a fallback. In my situation, I am using a plug-in which I do not want to modify in every part where this happens. I was thinking to rewrite the `Event.preventDefault` function by accessing the object's prototype, but I'm not sure how to proceed here, neither can I find any information on this.

This seems like the most obvious and elegant solution. Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: If you know how manipulating an object's prototype works in general - give it a try, and tell us what happens. If you don't - then research that topic first.

Comment: I just didn't know the correct object name, but the answer below cleared the problem ;) It worked - obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I usually do:

```
if (!Event.prototype.preventDefault)
    Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
        try {this.keyCode = 0;} catch (e) {}
        this.returnValue = false;
    }
```

Well, it *is* the most obvious solution. I can't exactly remember when, but sometimes you need to set the `keyCode` property to `0` to correctly prevent keyboard events.

Note: this works in IE8 *only*, as IE7 has no `Event` constructor.

Comment: It would be good to check if `preventDefault` is there first, to avoid overwriting the built-in version on browsers that do support it.

Comment: I know, duh :). But the question was asked because somebody was unsure how to modify the prototype, so it's good to show them how to do it properly in full.

Comment: @user2497157 The reason is in the answer.